# C# Console application wont post large dataset to asp.net .net core 3.0 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, post, .net-core

Im strugling with my last step of my console application. I have a post function which posts a car brand including models, generations, modifications and car data. As you can imagine thats a large dataset. Smaller brands are send no problem but when i come to bigger brands like audi , bmw and mercedes then my application doesnt post.

Here is the Console application code who sends the data

```
private static async Task PostDataSet(List<Brand> DataSet)
    {

        string key = Api_Key;
        if (key == null || key == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No key set");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Posting a batch with " + DataSet.Count + " items :" + DataSet[0].Name);
        try
        {
            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["Key"] = Api_Key;
                data["Dataset"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataSet).ToString();
                data["HostIp"] = Hostip;
                string ResponseString = "";
                if (UseLive)
                {
                    Uri x = new Uri(LiveUrl + "/Api/FullApiUpdate");
                    var response = await wb.UploadValuesTaskAsync(x, "POST", data);
                    ResponseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                    Console.WriteLine(ResponseString);
                }
                if (!UseLive)
                {
                    Uri x = new Uri(localurl + "/Api/FullApiUpdate");
                    var response = await wb.UploadValuesTaskAsync(x, "POST", data);
                    ResponseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                    Console.WriteLine(ResponseString);
                }
                if (ResponseString == "No api key specified" || ResponseString == "Invalid Api Key" || ResponseString == "Received null")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Api posted a cancellation token : " + ResponseString);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error posting to api");
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Everything works for smaller brands but like i told you earlier big brands break. The Server side api action looks like this

```
public async Task<string> FullApiUpdate(string Dataset , string HostIp, string Key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("API KEY ACCESED THIS ACTION : " + Key);
        Console.WriteLine("IP ACCESED THIS ACTION : " + HostIp);

        if (Key == null || Key == "")
        {
            return "No api key specified";
        }

        if (await _context.Api_Keys.Where(x=>x.Key == Key && x.Active == true).FirstOrDefaultAsync()==null)
        {
            return "Invalid Api Key";
        }

        if (Dataset != null || Dataset.Count() != 0)
        {
            List<Brand> FullSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Brand>>(Dataset);
            if (FullSet.Count() != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reveived a batch of " + FullSet.Count() + " items from : " + HostIp);
                await _context.AddRangeAsync(FullSet);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return "Updated a batch of " + FullSet.Count() + " Items";
            }
        }
        return "Received null";
    }
```

I dont really know where to go from here Here are the console outputs which i have.
Server :
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnqWn.png)
Console :
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9CcU.png)

i have tried this in my startup

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.BufferBody = false;
            x.KeyLengthLimit = 2048; // 2 KiB
            x.ValueLengthLimit = 4194304; // 32 MiB
            x.ValueCountLimit = 2048;// 1024
            x.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = 32; // 16
            x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 32768; // 16384
            x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = 256; // 128
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 134217728; // 128 MiB
        });
```

I have searched multiple forums but none of them worked for me. Any help is welcome

Comment: What exception are you getting? If possible, include a stack-trace. Or, is that not what you mean by "breaks"?

Comment: no it just return null. the api function doesnt receive anything. maybe is the post that im sending to large ? also edited my question to 'Doesnt post' instead of breaking

Comment: In that case, I recommend stepping through the problem area with a debugger, if you haven't already. It might also help if you added comments to your code explaining where the issue is exactly.

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont know why the api controller wont get the data. Is there a max size of data. maybe thats the limitation or a timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by increasing the size to int.maxvalue

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.BufferBody = false;
            x.KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // 2 KiB
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // 32 MiB
            x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;// 1024
            x.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue; // 16
            x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // 16384
            x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // 128
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // 128 MiB
        });
```